# Is there a way to add attachment during the "collect data from user" action in SPD workflow?

Tags: workflow

Is there a way to add attachment in the INFOPATH form during the "collect data from user" action in SPD workflow?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can do this out of the box. One suggestion might be to edit the form and add a link to the Attach File section on the list item where you are collecting the data. Another option may be to approach this differently and have a sharepoint workflow control the status of the item and use these custom actions for sharepoint designer which allow you to email attachments etc.

[Codeplex SharePoint SPD Custom Actions](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/)